# In Excel, how do I return the match number of a cell in a list (i.e. if it was the first or second match)

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I am trying to figure out how to find whether a cell was the first match, the second match etc... in a list. I know that COUNTIF() will tell you how many times some given value showed up in a list (e.g. 3 times), but I can't figure out how to know if a cell is the first appearance of a match or the second etc...

For example, say I had a list 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 and I pointed at the first number (1) to see if it was the first time number 1 showed up in that list, or the second number 1. Is there anyway to do something like this in Excel? Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to say that you are looking for OCCURRENCE of numbers ?

Comment: Ah yes I did. I should have been clearer. I have seen both answers now though.

Comment: Glad to help you @KLonge ,,, getting specific number's occurrence is an additional exercise but is useful too,,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. Quick and simple.

Answer (score 1):

**:Caveat:**

**Shown method works with all version of Excel.**

*I would like to show you that, how can you get the occurrence of numbers in column also, get specific number's occurrence.*

[image]

- Formula in cell C17:

  `=COUNTIF($A$17:$A17,A17)`

---

**Method for specific numbers:**

- Enter numbers in D15 to H15, which works as helper value.
- Formula in cell D17:

  `=IF($A17=D$15,COUNTIF($A$17:$A17,$A17),"")`

**N.B.**

- Fill formula across.
- You may adjust cell references in formula as needed.